# Php - Get video duration from a file hosted on amazon S3 server

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

I am developing back-end API with php to get the duration from a video file hosted on amazon S3. The API server is hosted on amazon EC2 and the video file is uploaded on amazon S3. The problem is when I request to API server, it has to response the information of the video file hosted on amazon S3 such as duration, file size, resolution etc. At least, it must response the video. I've followed codes by using ffmpeg such as below, but it's not working.

```
<?php
$file = 'https://videoapptest-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/video/10/44__55_f03876434e48d5fed7d6982b0cf578de_u_00000.ts';
$result = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . escapeshellcmd($file) . ' 2>&1');
preg_match('/(?<=Duration: )(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{2}/', $result, $match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

How can I get the video duration from a file hosted on amazon s3 with ffmpeg or another tool?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the error condition, or any other observation you can share? Have you tried running your code using a local file as a test?

Comment: Yes, on the localhost, it is working. exactly if the $file is local path, its working. But when $file is Url it is not working.

Comment: How large is the file? Are you considering it may require full transfer to run the `ffmpeg -i` command?